# Wrapping using withRouter forces PureComponent to update when there is no changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a most basic React PureComponent, wrapped with `withRouter`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import { shallowEqualExplain } from 'shallow-equal-explain';

class TestComp extends React.PureComponent{
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
        const shallowEqualExplanation = shallowEqualExplain(
            prevProps,
            this.props,
        );
        console.log("TEST COMP DID UPDATE", shallowEqualExplanation);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(TestComp);
```

**The component re-renders every time the parent is updated, even though no prop is passed down from the parent.**

Using [shallow equal explain](https://github.com/OliverJAsh/shallow-equal-explain) tells me that the `match` property sent by `withRouter` is changed even though my path is exactly the same.

Any idea how to fix that?

(I do not wish to use `shouldComponentUpdate` as it might work in this very simple example but is tedious to implement in all the components of my application)

Comment: Could you show how you're calling the child inside the parent?

Comment: @Dupocas I am simply doing `<TestComp/>`. No props whatsoever is passed down.